# Let $V$ be a vector space over an infinite field which cant be spanned by one vector. show the $V$ has infinite sub spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over an infinite field, $V$ cant be spanned by one vector. Prove the $V$ has infinite sub spaces.

My thoughts:
$V$ cant be spanned by one vector so it is at least spanned by $2$ vectors. 
$$V=sp\{u,v,...\}$$

Im finding it difficult to prove that that the following subspace are not equal
$$w_1=sp\{au+bv: a, b \mbox{ are scalars from the field}\}$$ and

$$w_2=sp\{cu+dv: c,d \mbox{ are scalars from the field that are not } a,b\}$$

What conditions do we need to put on those scalars in order
we wont have a scenario where $w1=w2$. In example $sp\{1,1\} = sp\{2,2\}$ despite the fact $a!=c , b!=d$ and after we put those conditions how do we prove that indeed $w1!=w2$?

Thanks alot!

Comment: When $(a,b)$ is not a multiple of $(c,d)$. In other words, when $ad-bc\ne 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite subspaces"? Maybe "infinitely many subspaces"? In this case, prove first that every affine line contains infinitely many elements.